# Internal consistency exception while choosing images from photo library

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an app in which user makes a post and chooses images from photo library but often while choosing image my app crashes and image picker gets stuck over there,  Following is the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This method can only be called from inside of -[PHPhotoLibrary performChanges:completionHandler:] or -[PHPhotoLibrary performChangesAndWait:error:]'
```

Please tell me what to do and how to avoid this exception. Why am i getting this exception?

Comment: What's the stack trace? It should show what's the last call you make that you shouldn't do.

Comment: Actually my app does not crash always but it seldom does. This confuses me about what the issue is. I will post here the stack trace if it crashes again. Mostly it crashes when using the app fast/quickly.

Comment: The error reason doesn't ring a bell?

Comment: no, it doesn't. I never heard some bell with this crash.

Comment: *ring a bell* means *point you to the right direction*. There is a method which is supposed to be called in two particular API.

Comment: it does not take me to code but to something highlighted lldb... and above mentioned exception in console/log.

Comment: There are multiple reasons for this to happen but I would guess that you're adding, removing, or updating `UITableViewCell` without keeping track of the count of cells correctly.

Comment: No there are no tables or cells. Flow is like: user fills post details > presses next > lands on images screen and taps on camera/photolibrary button > chooses image and here app stucks and app crashes. Not everytime but seldom